# java.lang.NullPointerException due to setupActionBar in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I hope the stack trace tells the story. As typical, I call `setupActionBar()` inside `onCreate` and the code for `setupActionBar()` is auto-generated

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Maybe someone else has experienced something like this. There is no red-line in my manifest, or layout, or string resources, or anywhere I can look.

```
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.game.example/com.game.example.WeaponActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.game.example.WeaponActivity.setupActionBar(WeaponActivity.java:103)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.game.example.WeaponActivity.onCreate(WeaponActivity.java:38)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-06 09:59:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Does your theme have an action bar?

Comment: @RaghavSood By theme do you mean "menu" resource?

Comment: No, I mean your Activity theme.

Comment: @RaghavSood I am not sure. I look in the style resource and don't see action bar. Where would I verify this?

Comment: @RaghavSood, @BillMote et al: I just noticed that all the activities preceding the failing one don't have any code pertaining to `setupActionBar()`. I had copied the failing activity (WeaponActivity) from another project. Are there certain arrangements that would cause android to generate the `setupActionBar()` code for some activities and not for others?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your application themed correctly in your manifest.

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo">
```

Verify that you've added the new activity to your manifest -- and that you haven't overridden the theme for it.

Comment: The manifiest has the following theme: `<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >` The activities leading to this one works fine (i.e. Login, ect). Only this one throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the method `setupActionBar()` and related code and it works.

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: You should edit your answer and place additional information rather than answering your question and then asking another question.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bill Mote said, I had the same issue (NullPointerException on setupActionBar()) I fixed that by changing the theme in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<application
...
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black
```

to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo
```

then everything is fine.